# How do I create a sigmoid-esque function with the following properties?

Tags: functions, special-functions

For a range of $x$ values between $A$ and $B$ I would like $f(x) \rightarrow x$.  For values less than $A$ I would like $f(x)$ to exhibit a sigmoid-esque convergence to $A'$  where $A'$  is $A - \delta$ for some small $\delta$.  Similarly, for values greater than $B$ I would like $f(x)$ to converge to $B'$ where $B'$ is $B+\delta$ for some small $\delta$.

Typical values will be $A = 0.5$, $B = 1.5$, $A' = 0.4$, $B' = 1.6$.

Comment: Do you need f(x) = x in [A,B] or just f(x) closely approximating x? If it is the former, you will need to use indicator functions, or, equivalently, a piecewise definition of f.

Comment: Close is probably good enough, but I can do a piecewise function too.  I've been trying to work out a piecemeal end points using tanh(x) or x^2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This image from Wikipedia shows several sigmoid-type functions, each with derivative 1 at the origin:

[image: sigmoid functions]

By taking any of these (choose one, and call it $g(x)$), translating, and rescaling gives you $B + \delta g((x-B)/\delta)$. This will serve as the upper end of your function. The "$B +$" is the vertical translation, the "$- B)$" is the horizontal translation, the factor of $\delta$ on the outside rescales $g$ vertically, and the factor of $\delta$ on the inside scales $g$ horizontally (making the derivative correct, so that you don't have a singular point in your piecewise function).

See this example that I typed into wolfram alpha with $g = \tanh$, $B = 1.5$, $\delta = 0.1$: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.5+%2B+0.1+*+tanh%28%28x-1.5%29%2F0.1%29](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.5%20%2b%200.1%20*%20tanh%28%28x-1.5%29/0.1%29)

[image]

You can work out the lower end of your function analogously.

$$
   f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       A + \delta\tanh((x-A)/\delta), & x \leq A \\
       x, & A < x < B \\
       B + \delta\tanh((x-B)/\delta), & x \geq B \\
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$

is one such function, but you don't need to use $\tanh$. If it's unclear how I arrived at this, it could be helpful to take each of the four transformations I performed on $\tanh$ and plotting them individually to see exactly how the function changes, and how the transformations act together to give you what you need.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and it works pretty well.  I'm using it to control camera zoom past min/max values.